# rails xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null ); error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I trying to make like button for each recipe

but if i click like button browser said

xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

return this errors

I don't know why this error occurred

this is my code in rails

`application.js`

```
function like(id){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/like/" + id,
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){
            if(data.result){
                $("#countlike").html("likes " + data.count);
                // $("#count").removeAttr('onclick');
                // $("#count").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`route.rb`

```
post '/like/:id'=>'recipes#like'
```

`views/recipes/show.html.erb`

```
<p>
  <a id = "countlike" onclick="like(<%=@recipe.id%>)">Like it</a>
</p>
```

`recipes_controller.rb`

```
  def like
      likes = Recipe.find(params[:id]).likes           
      result = likes.create 
      render json:{result: result, count: likes.count}
  end
```

It was work correctly in other project same code

Comment: Check the Rails logs, there should a full trace for the 500 error, which will tell you where's the problem

Comment: @a.barbieri it said 
Processing by RecipesController#like as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Comment: Do you have `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in your view?

Comment: @a.barbieri no! can i just  insert that code in my view?

Comment: This might be a good starting point. It should go in the `head`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are missing your data attribute in you post ajax request that might be throwing the error.

```
function like(id){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/like/" + id,
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data: my_data, // <--- HERE
        success: function(data){
            if(data.result){
                $("#countlike").html("likes " + data.count);
                // $("#count").removeAttr('onclick');
                // $("#count").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!